# How to export my local docker image to a tar and the load on another computer

Tags: linux, macos, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a local image on my windowns PC

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND             CREATED                  STATUS              PORTS
52f36432c9a7        visionai/clouddream:latest   "/bin/bash"         Less than a second ago   Up 3 minutes
```

Now I want to export it to a tar, so save in my flash disk and then load into my mac.

i try these but does not work:

```
    $ docker save -o visionai/clouddream clouddream.tar
Error response from daemon: No such image: clouddream.tar
```

and

```
$ docker export visionai/clouddream > clouddream.tar
Error response from daemon: No such container: visionai/clouddream
```

Answer (score 12):

The best way is use save/load commands because the CMD are saved. Using import/export commands the CMD is not saved.

Save to the disk your docker image:

```
docker save --output="image_name.tar" id_image
```

Load your docker image from the disc:

```
docker load --input image_name.tar
```

if after list images the repository and tag are < none >, you can rename your image setting new repository:tag

```
Docker tag new_repository:new_tag
```

Answer (score 6):

You inverted the parameters for the docker save:

```
docker save -o clouddream.tar visionai/clouddream
```

The docker export exports a **container** but you are trying to export an image so it can't work

Comment: where is this going to be saved ?

Comment: In a file name clouddream.tar

Comment: I mean the location, in my currently path ?

Comment: Yes.

Please note that by doing this you are not creating an image of your currently running container. You are saving the original 'visionai/clouddream' image as a tar. If you wish to save changes from the container you are running you will need to use [docker commit](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/) to create an image of it first.